# Entity Reference View as a 'Content' Field Select List only shows the last item

Tags: views, entities

I have a view that gets values from a series of paragraphs in a node. The view works, and shows a list of all of the values for a field, in each of the paragraphs.

I have an entity reference view, based on the above, that also shows the multiple items returned by the view.

In the Views preview, both the Page and the Entity Reference return a full list of values.

In a node, I have included an Entity Reference field and set this to get values from the Entity Reference View above. This field is presented to the use as a Select List.

When creating a node, the Select List only shows the last item returned by the Entity Reference View.

I have tried this on a clean install of Drupal, but it will never show anything but the last item returned from the View.

What? Why? I am confused.

[image: View]

---

[image: Dropdown]